# How to add a subtitle to label in javafx

Tags: label, javafx-8, subtitle

i am in need a label with a subtitle on it , exactly like in this
[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/su5cU.png)

the first thing that comes in mind is to extend the GridPane and make a new Custom pane something like:

```
package Components.CustomLabel;

import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;

/**
 *
 * @author Aamir khan
 */
public class LabelWithSubTitle extends GridPane {

private final Label title = new Label();
private final Label subTitle = new Label();
private final ImageView thumb = new ImageView();

public LabelWithSubTitle(String titleString, String subString, Image thumb) {
    setTitle(titleString);
    setSubTitle(subString);
    setThumb(thumb);
    init();
}

private void setSubTitle(String sub) {
    subTitle.setText(sub);
}

private void setThumb(Image img) {
    thumb.setImage(img);
}

private void setTitle(String titleString) {
    title.setText(titleString);
}

private void init() {
    add(thumb, 0, 0, 1, 2);
    add(title, 1, 0);
    add(subTitle, 1, 1);
  }

}
```

i am just totally new to this so any idea how can i achieve this?

Comment: What is problem with your code?

Comment: its not the proper way i think to do that..

Comment: Why do you think that this is not the proper way to do it?

Comment: so you guys think my Code is proper..!